# Error executing select query in sqlite by android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have write this code for select filtered data from sqlite db through android. But it says there are some error. Can you help me to correct my code please.

```
    category = data[0];
    district = data[1];

    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("dbumbers", 1, null);      

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM numbers where [category = '"+category+"'] and [district = '"+district+"']", null);
```

Comment: Please post your error log

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shehan.srilankaphones/com.shehan.srilankaphones.AllNumers}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: category = 'ambulance' (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM numbers where [category = 'ambulance'] and [district = 'ampara']

Comment: please check this. Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM numbers where category = '"+category+"' and district = '"+district+"'", null);
```

You must eliminate `[]` from your query